# Microservices: what are pros and cons?

Tags: architecture, microservices

What are pros and cons of using microservices in comparison with alternative architectures?
Is there a rule of thumb when microservices should be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pro's of micro-services are that your applications scale very well. You divide your application in tiny services. It's a hard thing to decide which bounded services you will need. But once you have done this, you can easy scale specific services up to multiple times (the services that actually get the most load) rather than needing to scale your whole application up.

Another advantage is that it is easier for new developers to start creating new features for your application, since everything is divided into these separated service --> Each service has its own (small) codebase.

The biggest disadvantage of using microservices are of course that there is a higher chance of failure during the communication between the different services.

The usage of microservices usually only starts paying off when your application is getting too big to maintain as a monolithic application.
Try starting as a monolithic but keep your bounded contexts in mind while developing (try to keep it as separated as possible) to you can migrate to microservices if needed later on.

Answer (score 47):

## Pros

---

Sam Newman in [Building Microservices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491950358), enumerates the key benefits of Microservices as following:

#### Technology Heterogeneity

With    a   system  composed    of  multiple,   collaborating   services,   we  can decide  to  use different
technologies    inside  each    one.    This    allows  us  to  pick    the right   tool    for each    job,    rather  than
having  to  select  a   more    standardized,   one-size-fits-all   approach    that    often   ends    up  being
the lowest  common  denominator.

#### Resilience

A   key concept in  resilience  engineering is  the *bulkhead*. If  one component   of  a   system
fails,  but that    failure doesn’t cascade,    you can isolate the problem and the rest    of  the
system  can carry   on  working.    Service boundaries  become  your    obvious bulkheads.  In  a
monolithic  service,    if  the service fails,  everything  stops   working.    With    a   monolithic
system, we  can run on  multiple    machines    to  reduce  our chance  of  failure,    but with
microservices,  we  can build   systems that    handle  the total   failure of  services    and degrade
functionality   accordingly.

#### Scaling

With    a   large,  monolithic  service,    we  have    to  scale   everything  together.   One small   part    of
our overall system  is  constrained in  performance,    but if  that    behavior    is  locked  up  in  a
giant   monolithic  application,    we  have    to  handle  scaling everything  as  a   piece.  With
smaller services,   we  can just    scale   those   services    that    need    scaling,    allowing    us  to  run
other   parts   of  the system  on  smaller,    less    powerful    hardware.

#### Ease of  Deployment

A   one-line    change  to  a   million-line-long   monolithic  application requires    the whole
application to  be  deployed    in  order   to  release the change. That    could   be  a   large-impact,
high-risk   deployment. In  practice,   large-impact,   high-risk   deployments end up  happening
infrequently    due to  understandable  fear.

With    microservices,  we  can make    a   change  to  a   single  service and deploy  it  independently
of  the rest    of  the system. This    allows  us  to  get our code    deployed    faster. If  a   problem does
occur,  it  can be  isolated    quickly to  an  individual  service,    making  fast    rollback    easy    to
achieve.

#### Organizational   Alignment

Microservices   allow   us  to  better  align   our architecture    to  our organization,   helping us
minimize    the number  of  people  working on  any one codebase    to  hit the sweet   spot    of  team
size    and productivity.   We  can also    shift   ownership   of  services    between teams   to  try to  keep
people  working on  one service colocated.

#### Composability

One of  the key promises    of  distributed systems and service-oriented    architectures   is  that
we  open    up  opportunities   for reuse   of  functionality.  With    microservices,  we  allow   for our
functionality   to  be  consumed    in  different   ways    for different   purposes.   This    can be
especially  important   when    we  think   about   how our consumers   use our software.

#### Optimizing   for Replaceability

If  you work    at  a   medium-size or  bigger  organization,   chances are you are aware   of  some
big,    nasty   legacy  system  sitting in  the corner. The one no  one wants   to  touch.  The one that
is  vital   to  how your    company runs,   but that    happens to  be  written in  some    odd Fortran
variant and runs    only    on  hardware    that    reached end of  life    25  years   ago.    Why hasn’t  it
been    replaced?   You know    why:    it’s    too big and risky   a   job.

With    our individual  services    being   small   in  size,   the cost    to  replace them    with    a   better
implementation, or  even    delete  them    altogether, is  much    easier  to  manage.

## Cons

---

The most important disadvantage of Microservices is that they   have    all the associated  complexities    of
distributed systems,    and while   we  have    learned a   lot about   how to  manage  distributed
systems well    it  is  still   hard.   If  you’re  coming
from    a   monolithic  system  point   of  view,   you’ll  have    to  get much    better  at  handling
deployment, testing,    and monitoring  to  unlock  the benefits.   You’ll
also    need    to  think   differently about   how you scale   your    systems and ensure  that    they    are
resilient.  Don’t   also    be  surprised   if  things  like    distributed transactions    or  *CAP    theorem*
start   giving  you headaches,  either!

## Closing Remarks

---

Just quoting from [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html):

> One reasonable argument we've heard is that you shouldn't start with a
> microservices architecture. Instead begin with a monolith, keep it
> modular, and split it into microservices once the monolith becomes a
> problem.

Comment: Cons include mysterious problems that occur time to time but everything seems to be working. You can't reproduce them, in single application state of app would be more contained whereas in spread out stage states of several services align in certain way that cause error. You have to observer error pattern for longer periods

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Totally agree. Distributed Tracing and Monitoring is a must for such applications

Answer (score 2):

**Advantages**

1.Decentralized and Decoupled Architecture, using choreography rather than orchestration makes services publish-subscribe based and as a result fully decentralized

2.Do one thing and do it well (Unix philosophy), more focused and singular with very narrow functionality

3.Easy to have parallelism and load balancing, because of being more fine-grained from the business process point of view

4.Statelessness, however, having a stateful Microservice is valid but it is not the ideal

5.Individual data storage makes services relaxed to keep tracing the data-flow

6.Easy and automated deployment and discovery due to use of container engine-based technologies such as docker

7.More interoperability, which makes services able to have more flexibility in accepting/dropping a new/current service or protocol

8.Fully compatible with Representational state transfer (REST) which allows creating stateless services

9.Suitable for discrete systems, for example for batch automation process

**Disadvantages**
1.Service synchronization, keeping services synchronized in a cooperative way

2.Difficult to find systematic problems, for example, finding a problem in a chain of business activities when there is a logical error in the process is more difficult and it requires to combine several log files into one piece

3.Automated deployment and discovery is a must when the number of microservices is more than a few

4.Difficult to find the right service granularity, which can lead the entire system into instability due to overwhelmed network communication and error rations

5.Challenging when the business system is not discrete enough, like continues process control

6.Developing an automated test is significant difficult than monolithic systems

Following are a set of articles that published about microservices in code-project, you can read and comment on your questions if you like.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-I https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-II https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264113/Dive-into-Microservices-Architecture-Part-III

Answer (score 0):

We can say deployment is easier for micro services but any change has to be additive only. because anybody who depends on it can fail. So the separation of concern is not there as much as like to. Also, tracing failures is no fun. Also during development, requires something available all the time for others to be able to make a call. otherwise development suffers. With monolithic application, we know what is there. But with distributed world no one know what is there or if anything even exists.